# LateInitializationError: Field 'displayName' has not been initialized in Flutter's Shared Prefrence?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I am creating an Flutter application in which i need to store the user information and for some extent i am able to achieve it with Shared Prefrence.

i am storing the data at login screen as follows:

```
    var displayName=jsondata["username"];
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('displayName', displayName);
```

and on my drawerScreen i am getting the same data as follows:

```
 late String displayName;
 initState() {
  getData();
  super.initState();
 }
 getData() async{
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')!;
 }
```

but whenever i click on drawer button there is an error as shown:

> LateInitializationError: Field 'displayName' has not been initialized.

**but when i hot reload my app while drawer is opened there is no error** when i go to other screen and get back to drawer the LateInitialization errro arises,

i dont know what causing this error

[image: here is the How error arises]

and this is the other screen where i am shifting from drawer:

```
 late String displayName;

getData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')!;
  print(displayName);
  }  

initState() {
   getData();
   super.initState();
 }

     @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
     key: _scaffoldKey,
     drawer: SizedBox(
       width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75 < 400 ? 
     MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.75 : 350,
       child: Drawer(
       child: AppDrawer(
        selectItemName: 'Home',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
    title: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        SizedBox(
          height: AppBar().preferredSize.height,
          width: AppBar().preferredSize.height + 40,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  _scaffoldKey.currentState!.openDrawer();
                },
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.dehaze,
                  color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6!.color,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
```

can someone suggest me a better way of doing it . Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Can you please share the code of `Drawer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to to add setState();

```
late String displayName;
initState() {
getData();
super.initState();
 }
 Future getData() async{
 SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
 setState(() {
  displayName=prefs.getString('displayName')!;
  });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `initState` is not `async` (and it can't be `async`), so your `getData` will likely (or surely) be completed later than the `build` method is called. Since you set `displayName` in `getData`, and you marked it as `late`, you will get this error. That's why it is working after hot reload, because at that time `displayName` is already initalized.

One possible solution is to call `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` (this is why your `getData` needs to be `async`) somewhere earlier in your application, for example in `main() async` function, store the result of `getInstance` using a `ChangeNotifierProvider` (or any other way that allows you to use this value in this widget), and use its value in `getData`. This way `getData` does not need to be `async`, and `displayName` will be initalized before `build` method is called. This can be useful if you use `SharedPreferences` in more than one place, because you don't have to `await` the result of `getInstance` each time.

Another approach is not declaring `displayName` as `late`, but allow it to be `null`, and then in the `build` method you can use a `FutureBuilder` which completes upon `getData` is executed, and the building of `Scaffold` will only be started after this future completes. In this case you can display a progress indicator while the future is not completed.